# Unittesting Pyramid/Cornice resource with query string in a URL

Tags: python, python-requests, pyramid, python-unittest, cornice

I have Pyramid/cornice resource, that requires a ?query=keyword in end of the url. But I don't know how to add this in a pyramid's dummyRequest object. Code works perfectly on browser and I will get correct response when using this url to get stuff: `*url*/foo?query=keyword`.

My class/resource is defined like this:

```
@resource(path='/bar/search/foo')
class SearchFooResource(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view(renderer='json')
    def get(self):
        #get query string, it's a tuple
        req = self.request.GET.items()
        #do stuff with req
```

Now req should contain the all the query string 'stuffs' in a list that contains them as a tuple's, for example: `[('query', 'bar'),('query', 'asd')]`.  But how do I make unittest to this resource? I can't seem to add anything to `self.request.GET.items()` method. When running unittest `req` is empty, and I will get this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`.

My current unittest:

```
def test_passing_GetFooBaarResource(self):
    request = testing.DummyRequest()
    request.GET = [('query', 'keyword')]    
    info = SearchFooResource.get(SearchFooResource(request))

    self.assertEqual(info['foo'], 'baar')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @matino has suggested, you can just use a plain dictionary (instead of a list of tuples you tried).

```
def test_passing_GetFooBaarResource(self):
    request = testing.DummyRequest()
    request.GET = {'query': 'keyword'}   
    info = SearchShowResource.get(SearchShowResource(request))

    self.assertEqual(info['foo'], 'baar')
```

This will work in uncomplicated cases where you don't have multiple parameters with the same name (`/someurl?name=foo&name=baz&name=bar`).

If you need to test those more complicated queries you can replace your DummyRequest's GET attribute with a WebOb [MultiDict](https://webob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#multidict)

```
from webob.multidict import MultiDict

def test_passing_GetFooBaarResource(self):
    request = testing.DummyRequest()
    request.GET = MultiDict([('query', 'foo'), ('query', 'bar'), ('query', 'baz')])    
    info = SearchShowResource.get(SearchShowResource(request))

    self.assertEqual(info['foo'], 'baar')
```

Then, normally, in your actual view method, if you need to handle multiple parameters with the same name you use `request.GET.getall('query')` which should return `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.

In simpler cases you can just use `request.GET['query']` or `request.GET.get('query', 'default')`. I mean, your use of `request.GET.items()` is a bit unusual...

Comment: `request.GET.getall('query')` problem is that when there are no query or just one, it gives an error. `.items()` just works in all cases, but it requires some parsing. But yeah, this answer solves my problem how to add 'query' twice in the request.

Comment: @MiroK.: Actually, looking at the sources, it doesn't look like `.getall('query')` ever fails if there are no values or there's just one. It returns an empty list or a list with just one value in those cases.

Comment: Well you are absolutely correct. Reason why it didn't seem to work was how my unittest were done at first. When using `testing.DummyRequest(params={'query': 'foo'})` `.getall('query')` failed each time. But when using multidict to give values or leaving it empty, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/testing.html#pyramid.testing.DummyRequest) I think you need to pass it as `params` argument (not tested):

```
request = testing.DummyRequest(params={'query': 'keyword'})
```